# Rotation Animations for background views overlaps button in foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I created a animation to switch locations. The animation works fine, but it destroys the button in the foreground.

The button should not be affected. What is causing this?

[image]

a [video](https://drive.google.com/a/goeuro.com/file/d/0B5R6qXDaqLpWeEdhSVNRMjN4M00/view)

```
 CGFloat speedFactor = 3.0;
 CABasicAnimation *slotAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.x"];
 [slotAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:M_PI_2]];
 [slotAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
 [slotAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeBoth];
 slotAnimation.duration = .3 / speedFactor;
 [[self.fromPositionTextField layer] addAnimation:slotAnimation forKey:@"slotAnimation"];

 CABasicAnimation *slotAnimation2 = [slotAnimation copy];
 [slotAnimation2 setBeginTime:CACurrentMediaTime()+0.3 / speedFactor];
 [[self.toPositionTextField layer] addAnimation:slotAnimation2 forKey:@"slotAnimation"];
 dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(.6 / speedFactor * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     NSArray *positions = @[self.viewModel.fromPosition, self.viewModel.toPosition];
     self.viewModel.fromPosition = positions[1];
     self.viewModel.toPosition = positions[0];

     CABasicAnimation *slotAnimation3 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.x"];
     [slotAnimation3 setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI *.125/4.0]];
     [slotAnimation3 setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
     [slotAnimation3 setFillMode:kCAFillModeBoth];
     slotAnimation3.duration = .3 / speedFactor;
     [slotAnimation3 setBeginTime:CACurrentMediaTime()+0.3 / speedFactor];
     [[self.fromPositionTextField layer] addAnimation:slotAnimation3 forKey:@"slotAnimation2"];

     CABasicAnimation *slotAnimation4 = [slotAnimation3 copy];
     [slotAnimation4 setBeginTime:CACurrentMediaTime()+0.6 /speedFactor];
     [[self.toPositionTextField layer] addAnimation:slotAnimation4 forKey:@"slotAnimation2"];

     dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.2/speedFactor * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [self.fromPositionTextField.layer removeAllAnimations];
         [self.toPositionTextField.layer removeAllAnimations];

     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the zPosition property of the button's layer (it's a CALayer object) to change the z-index of the button.

```
myButton.layer.zPosition = 100;
```

Larger values are "on top". The default value is 0.

You need to import the QuartzCore framework to access the layer.

[edit] Changed answer to 100 incase it is just copied rather than the comments read